# How to find full/real email address from Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there any way to get the full set of email addresses? Example: I receive an email sent to a Lotus group 'all department employees'. I'd like to be able to grab the actual email addresses contained within (not their Lotus user name) so that I could email everyone from a client other than Lotus. Does such an option exist? I believe this was doable in Exchange with a right-click and 'expand nickname' type of action. I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac and your document in edit mode, click on the group name and right click. Select "Show Name Details...".

If nothing shows up, check your status bar to see if there are any connection errors and add the required connection document if needed.

This should then pop-up a dialog box detailing the group details.

If the person is using a personal group list, or intentionally hidden the SendTo however you are not going to be able to see the details.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, Open any email, 
Go to file -> Save As , save as .eml on your desktop
open the file created on your desktop using notepad.

Comment: You call that 'very simple' ?

Comment: @Rabarberski Why, do you call that 'very hard'?

Comment: @jacob: I never said it's 'very hard', I just think it is /not/ 'very simple'. It's very involved: why would one need to save an email to a file and open it in another application just to see the actual email addresses?

Answer (score 2):

I found it!  I just don't understand why it's so hard to do...

Looking at an email message, click "Details" to expand the header.
With the header expanded, right click on the contact name.
In the context menu, choose Send->Email.
The "To" field of the new draft email message will contain the full email address.

I was just forced into Lotus Notes 8.5 and had the exact same quesiton.
More specifically, I wanted to COPY an email address out to paste elsewhere.
Doesn't sound like too much to ask for, does it?

If all you want to do is LOOK at an email address, Lotus provides two inconvenient ways to do it:

1. You can expand an email header by clicking "Details".
   Right click on the contact name, and select "Name Details".
   THEN, in the Details dialog, click on the "Name Information" tab.
   On that tab, you can SEE the email address.  You can even highlight the text.
   But you CANNOT copy it.
   (WHY NOT? The Lotus engineers had to go OUT OF THEIR WAY to do that to us...)
2. Or, right click the contact name and view their "business card."
   In this view I have also been able to view, but not copy, email addresses.

Comment: It is "rich" text.  If you open WordPad you can select the text, drag and drop to wordpad, then copy it.

Comment: Yea it's lame, typing into a "To:" field worked, but under my "Name Information" tab that you describe it does not show email addresses for me.  Lotus Oats 8.5

Answer (score 0):

If the article [Public Address Book Contact Group Reply to All Fault](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/dba3ca7e515d55ff85256a0700727b35/3ffd6819a8686a6d8525791f004a1e9d?OpenDocument) still applies, then your problem is because you are using a server address book for the email.

Apparently the problem doesn't occur when using a local address book, and the recipients can successfully reply to all in the group.

<sub>(Not using Lotus Notes, I cannot test anything.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do it that I know of, although you could potentially write an agent to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open Lotus Notes address book or your personal address book and search for the recipient. Property that user and you can copy the email address from there.

As a programmer and a user, I DO NOT understand why Lotus Notes doesn't allow users to copy the email address from "Show name details" screen. In my opinion, Lotus Notes is very poor design and not user friendly. Users will have to use Lotus Notes in case they are FORCED to. Overall, Lotus Notes is a bad product from a user's perspective.