# Display full/real email address from Lotus Notes?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

Similar but different to [How to find full/real email address from Lotus Notes?](https://superuser.com/questions/224994/how-to-find-full-real-email-address-from-lotus-notes)

I want to display the full email address when someone sends me an email. Right now it only shows their display name (eg "John Smith") and cannot figure out how to get John's full email without looking him up in the company directory. Even if I click show details it still only shows his display name. Any way to do this?

Comment: When I use "Show Details" I see the full email address (both for internal and external senders). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: When you do show details, it should so an expanded To and From under the regular heading and display the whole address.  If it's another Notes user, the address will be the Notes canonical format though and not the @whatever.com format.  It'll be like JOE BOB/XXX/COMPANYNAME if it's another Notes user and not an internet address.

Answer (score 1):

When you do show details, it should so an expanded To and From under the regular heading and display the whole address. If it's another Notes user, the address will be the Notes canonical format though and not the @whatever.com format. (Not sure if you need @xxxx.com address when you say 'full email address' or if you just need an email address that Notes will recognize') It'll be like JOE BOB/XXX/COMPANYNAME if it's another Notes user and not an internet address.

You can also just hit reply and it'll fill in the address. Then hit esc to cancel the reply.

You didn't mention which version of Notes, so I'm assuming 8.5.x

Answer (score 1):

I'm using DWA, so YMMV, but I have a "More" menu that has a "Show MIME Header" command, and that shows the joe@whatever.com address even when "Show Details" shows only the JOE BOB/XXX/WHATEVER form:

[image: iNotes "More" menu showing "Show MIME Header" command]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using HCL Notes 11 not sure if this applies to earlier versions.

From Mail tab choose the More drop down menu and select Preferences:

[image: Preferences]

From here tick "Show display names as internet address" from the Mail -> Basics -> Message Options headings

[image: Show display names]

Now when selecting a mail message I can see full @...com email addresses even for those within our company.